# Реализация алгоритмов двумерных массивов

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

В двумерном массиве С (n, n), состоящем из целых чисел вычислить:
• количество и произведение нечетных элементов;
• сумму квадратов элементов главной диагонали, расположенных между максимальным и минимальным элементами массива.

Не получается вторая часть задания.

Comment: читаете, как устроен цикл for, оператор if, и реализуете задачу.

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться)

Answer (score 2):

```
int data[4][4] = {
    {1,2,2,0},
    {1,3,4,5},
    {9,6,11,7},
    {4,2,1,6}
};
int n = 4;
int nodd_co = 0; // подсечт нечетных
int nodd_mult = 1; // произведение нечетных
//! нечетные элементы: x&1(битовое выделение четности равносильно x%2)
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (size_t j = 0; j < n; j++){
        if(data[i][j]&1){
            nodd_co++;
            nodd_mult*=data[i][j];
        }
    }
}
// несовсвем понятно, что имеется ввиду под " сумму квадратов элементов главной диагонали, 
//расположенных между максимальным и минимальным элементами массива."
// просто сумма квадартов диагонали
int ssum = 0, sum = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++){
    ssum+=data[i][i]*data[i][i];
}
// минимум и максимум на главной диагонали
int mx = INT_MIN, mn = INT_MAX;
int mxi, mni;
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if(mx<data[i][i]){
        mx = data[i][i];
        mxi = i;
    }
    if (mn>data[i][i]){
        mn = data[i][i];
        mni = i;
    }
}
for (size_t i = min(mni,mxi) /*+1, если надо не включительно */; 
i < max(mxi,mni)/*+1, если надо включительно */; i++){
    sum+=data[i][i]*data[i][i];
}
```

Comment: `несовсвем понятно, что имеется ввиду под ...` -- я бы интерпретировал это как -- элемент принадлежит главной диагонали и его адрес между адресами минимального и максимального элементов (вместо адресов можно использовать выражение из индексов -- `i * m + j` (i -- индекс строки массива, m --  количество элементов в строке)

Comment: Ну как бы если мы используем выражения из индексов то, пожалуйста, это надо было уточнить в вопросе, из выражения данного в вопросе непонятно что требуется, то ли минимумы  лежат на главное диагонали, то ли нет

Comment: Конечно (для @Neuro), надо бы уточнить. Боюсь ТС даже в голову не пришло спросить это у того, кто ему задачку дал. (кстати, перед ответом смотрите на ники авторов вопроса и комметария)

Comment: @avp, мне нужно на главной диагонали матрицы найти max и min элементы. и между ними найти сумму квадратов элементов. (матрица квадратная)

Comment: @WalerijaSchybika, и что именно у вас не получилось? Впрочем, данный ответ как раз показывает то, что вам нужно (можете отметить его "галкой")

Comment: @avp, благодарю за помощь! у меня как раз были проблемы с решением второго пункта задания. но у меня получилось найти решение. (P.S я новичок на этой платформе. только разбираюсь с предложенными функциями. )